# mediaelement.js how do I set the pluginPath variable

Tags: mediaelement.js

I followed the installation instructions, but when viewed on the website, all I see is a black box (no controls, nothing). I expect that I have an installation error.

Looking at the javascript with Firebug, I noticed that pluginPath was not set properly. Through google, found that this could be set like:

$('video').mediaelementplayer({pluginPath: '/var/www/html/equimed/libs/mediaelement/build/'});

I still get the black box. Is this the correct method to set the pluginPath? Is there a problem with an absolute path vs. a relative path? What is the best method to debug this as I'd really like to use mediaelement.js

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Success! By using a relative pluginPath the js was able to find both the plugins and media files.

In summary: I found that in using mediaelements.js, if you move the js and plugins found in the build/ directory (as I did to minify and consolidate js files), you need to specify the pluginPath in the jquery call. I had success by using a relative path from the location of the js to the original location of the build/ directory.